# error generated

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void);

{

float input ;

char input2 ;


    printf ("эта программа может переводить значегия из секунд в минуты часы или дни но только что то одно из этого\n");

    printf ("\n введите значение (секунды)");
    scanf ( " %d " , input);

    printf ("\nв какую величину вы хотите перевести ? минуты часы или дни \n если дни то введите d (day) если часы то введите c (clock) если минуты то введите m (minutes)");
    scanf (" %c " , input2);

    if (input2 == m)
    {

        input /= 60; 
        printf ("\n %f минут " , input);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Компилятор пишет то что в 5 строке ошибка но почему?

Вот код ошибки:

```
error: expected identifier or '('
{
^
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уберите точку с запятой после этого:

```
int main (void);
```

Возьмите `m` в кавычки.

Добавьте взятие адреса в вызовах `scanf`.

В `scanf ( " %d " , &input);` либо замените `%d` на `%f`, либо измените тип `input` на `int`.

После ввода секунд сбрасывайте буфер `stdin`, иначе чтение символа будет считывать оставшийся в буфере `\n`.